# Create coordinate polygon without azimuth

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a GeoTIFF bitmap from coordinates and data, the coordinates are given as a list and the data is in a saw list of lists. Now I create a polygon of coordinates using the haversine formula, but due to incorrect azimuth data, the graph turns out bad.

```
Xdata=x + 20 * np.cos(azimut * np.pi / 180) / (6371000 *np.pi/ 180)
Ydata=y + 20 * np.sin(azimut * np.pi / 180) / np.cos(x* np.pi / 180) / (6371000 * np.pi / 180)
a=len(Zdata) 
#
x_intep=(Xdata-x)/a-1
step_count = a
step = [ ( x[i] - Xdata[i] ) / (step_count - 1) for i in range( len(Xdata) ) ]
lat_a = []
for i in range( step_count ):
    lat_a.append( [Xdata[j] + step[j]*i for j in range( len(Xdata) ) ] )
```

[image]

Is there an easier way to create such a coordinate polygon.

Comment: I don't understand your goal. Is it making a buffer zone around a line/list of coordinates in meters?

Comment: @bugmenot123 yes, the buffer zone is a list of lists of coordinates